# Swift ResearchKit export answer with no ConsentDocument

Tags: iphone, swift, export, researchkit

I am making an enterprise app using ResearchKit.

I am now in the step of making a pdf with the answers gathered and emailing it.

I know that if you have a Consent Document this is the code for it:

ConsentDocument .makePDFWithCompletionHandler({ (NSData pdfFile, NSError error) -> Void in

```
        // println("pdf created")

        // finding document path  //TODO: Remove if not needed

        let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] .stringByAppendingPathComponent("Consent.pdf")

        pdfFile!.writeToFile(documentsPath, atomically: false)

        println(consentDocumentFromDirectory)

    })
```

But what if I do not have a Consent Document?

How should I create the pdf?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, *ResearchKit* doesn't currently support *HTML* or *PDF* output for regular question steps. After finishing a task, you'll need to manually and recursively process `ORKTaskResult` and convert them to a suitable format of your choice.

---

There's an ongoing [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/ResearchKit/ResearchKit/issues/479) discussing the possibility of adding printing support (as *HTML* output) to *ResearchKit*, which is exactly what you'd need.

If this is done, converting such *HTML* output into a *PDF* file would be trivial. However, I'm afraid that progress on this issue seems to have stalled recently and I'm not sure if anybody is currently working on it.